# Dynamic subtype lookup for Command Line application

Tags: java, reflection, command-line-interface

I am building a command line application in Java that has dynamic list of parameters depending on the first chosen parameter.

`java -jar cli.jar --optimizer DifferentialEvolution [optimizer options]`

An optimizer in this application is defined by implementing the interface `InterfaceOptimizer`. Using the [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library I am looking up all subtypes of this interface and choose the one that matches the name given in the command line.

Each implementation of an optimizer has different parameters that are marked with an annotaction `@Parameter(name = 'cli-name', description = "Some option")`. Parameters can be simple types which are easy to handle or complex types. For all complex types I need to perform the same lookup of subtypes that I do for the optimizers:

```
public static Map<String, Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer>> createOptimizerList() {
    Map<String, Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer>> optimizerList = new TreeMap<String, Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer>>();

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("eva2.optimization.strategies");
    Set<Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer>> optimizers = reflections.getSubTypesOf(InterfaceOptimizer.class);
    for(Class<? extends InterfaceOptimizer> optimizer : optimizers) {
        // We only want instantiable classes
        if(optimizer.isInterface() || Modifier.isAbstract(optimizer.getModifiers())) {
            continue;
        }
        optimizerList.put(optimizer.getSimpleName(), optimizer);
    }
    return optimizerList;
}
```

Since java can't handle dynamic generics (`Class type = Foobar.class; Class<? extends type>`) I need another way to perform the lookup so don't have to implement the above method for all parameterizable complex types.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The given code is syntacly correct and should work as it is. For more detailed answers please provide a runtime error or compiler warning/error.